# Javascript app with local communication

Tags: javascript, cordova

I was reading around to see if I can find an answer to my problem but no luck so far, so I hope someone can help me.

What I'm trying to do is a mobile app (ios, android, windows phone) that can communicate over lan wifi but without the need of internet to share info. For example a variable or plain text, or for example to use my phone as local server to share a pdf file. By the way I'm going to use phonegap so an answer must be in plain javascript/html/css please.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a server in javascript that runs on your phone?

Comment: Yes , sorry about my bad english

Comment: What im really trying to do is an mobile app to share info over LAN, lets take this example: a multiplayer game of chess over LAN, the 2 mobile apps are sharing info without internet, just the  lan wifi, its that posible to do programming only in javascript